# I cannot found modules in Django

Tags: django, windows, mongodb

I'm trying to connect my Django with my MongoDB.
So, first of all, I install this:

```py
pip install djongo
```

And all go fine, no errors.
But If you see my models.py archive:
[image: models.py]
It's like Django it's not finding and I can't import the models.
I tried to install again Django, but it says to me that it's already installed.
[image: CMD-ALREADY-INSTALLED]
I think I'm installing this in another path or something like that, but I don't know how to solve this.
My Django archive its in C:\PROYECTOS\PageSpeed_Insights__Selenium-Python\miweb

Comment: Looks like it's an environment issue. Does the code still run (i.e., is this just an issue with the linting in your editor)? If not, can you include the error you're getting?

Comment: Indeed, this is just an issue with your IDE (is it pycharm), you need to tell it to use your virtual environment so that it can see djongo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are installing `djongo` in your virtualenv `paginaweb`, you have to configure `PyCharm` (or whatever IDE you are using) to look for the packages in that virtualenv, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) you can see how to do it for `PyCharm`. It should work after that.